# How to subtract vector from scalar in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have parquet file which contain two columns (id,features).I want to subtract features from scalar and divide output by another scalar.
[parquet file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG7PM.jpg)

```
df.withColumn("features", ((df("features")-constant1)/constant2))
```

but give me error

> requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match. Old column
>   names (2): id, features New column names (1): features
>   How to solve it?

Comment: this part of code looks good, are you renaming your df in next lines?

Comment: No,but I want to save output in parquet file as df..write.parquet("file:///usr/local/data").

Answer (score 0):

My scala spark code to this as below . Only way to do any operation on vector sparkm datatype is casting to string. Also used UDF to perform subtraction and division.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
var df = Seq((1, Vectors.dense(35)),
  (2, Vectors.dense(45)),
  (3, Vectors.dense(4.5073)),
  (4, Vectors.dense(56)))
  .toDF("id", "features")
df.show()
val constant1 = 10
val constant2 = 2
val performComputation = (s: Double, val1: Int, val2: Int) => {
  Vectors.dense((s - val1) / val2)
}
val performComputationUDF = udf(performComputation)
df.printSchema()
df = df.withColumn("features",
  regexp_replace(df.col("features").cast("String"),
    "[\\[\\]]", "").cast("Double")
)

df = df.withColumn("features",
  performComputationUDF(df.col("features"),
    lit(constant1), lit(constant2))
)
df.show(20, false)

// Write State should with mode overwrite
df.write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .parquet("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/output1/")
```

Result

```
+---+----------+
|id |features  |
+---+----------+
|1  |[12.5]    |
|2  |[17.5]    |
|3  |[-2.74635]|
|4  |[23.0]    |
+---+----------+
```

Comment: but parquet file of output not appear. what's wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to write this as modified parquet file or do you have issues reading the source parquet file itself.

Comment: parquet file be the same after subtract.val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/model/data/user/part-r-00000-7d55ba81-5761-4e36-b488-7e6214df2a68.snappy.parquet").toDF("id","features")
//df.show(20)
val constant1 = 2.4848911616270923
val constant2 = 1.8305483113586494
val performComputation = (s: Double, val1: Double, val2: Double) => {
  Vectors.dense((s - val1) / val2)
df.withColumn("features", ((df("features")-val1)/val2))
}
df.write.parquet("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/output1")

Comment: Hey @SalmaElzeheiry . 
I have modified the code as per your requirement. Please test it. Because I was not writing data i didn't modify and store final dataframe with computed result, as I was only doing a show() statement. Its fixed now and with the ideal write statement as well.  :)

Comment: I want to read parquet file and do subtract and division on it.Not limit sequence.

Comment: It is doing substract and then division, just through a UDF . If you check this code :
 performComputationUDF(df.col("features"),
    lit(constant1), lit(constant2))
Its calling the udf and as per udf's definition it first subtracts by constant1 and divides by constant2