# How to subtracting two vectors in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, vector, normalization, parquet

I have parquet file which contain id,features [original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Meo.jpg).I want to subtract features from repeated value 2.484 as vector and put output in the same column(features). As Z-score to normalize data I want to apply (features-2.484)/1.830.

```
    val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/model/data/user/part-r-00000-7d55ba81-5761-4e36-b488-7e6214df2a68.snappy.parquet").toDF("id","features")

    implicit class Rep(n: Int) {
    def times[A](f: => A): Seq[A] = { 1 to n map(_ => f) } 
    }

  val myHis = 13849.times { println("2.4848911616270923")}
```

How to make repeated value as vector and subtract it?

Comment: Can you give some example input/expected output. Currently it's not very clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I put more details about data.I want subtact vector from vector . @Shaido

Comment: StandardScaler should work for you if you want to normalize the data, see: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/ml-features.html#standardscaler otherwise this should be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58358330/how-to-subtract-vector-from-scalar-in-scala

Comment: you can't subtract vector from scalar mathematically.you should convert scalar to vector to find output.